# Joins in Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have two classes in my model

```
[Table("tblPackages")]
public class Packages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "No of SMS")]
    public int AllowedSMS { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Span in Days")]
    public int? TimeSpan { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}


[Table("tblPackageTypes")]
public class PackageTypes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

and the table is same. now i need to get all from class `Packages` and just `Name` from class PackageTypes. How can i do by just using Entity Framework

Answer (score 2):

Add a PackageTypes navigation property to your Packages class and access it by name:

```
[Table("tblPackages")]
public class Packages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public int PackageTypesId { get; set; }
    public PackageTypes PackageTypes { get; get; }

    [Display(Name = "No of SMS")]
    public int AllowedSMS { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Span in Days")]
    public int? TimeSpan { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

By convention, Entity Framework will match the `PackageTypesId` and `PackageTypes` properties based on the naming (although you can use different names if you configure it to do so, but that's a more advanced topic).

Now you can access the Name directly from your Packages objects:

```
myPackage.PackageTypes.Name
```

Also, you might want to think about your classes in the singular, not the plural.  The class represents a single Package, not the entire collection.  Same with the PackageType.  It makes your code more understandable:

```
Package myPackage = new Package();
myPackage.PackageType.Name
```

Only use plural if your class truly represents the entire collection and not a single item.

Answer (score 1):

Use a navigation property, you will need a FK relationship between Packages and PackageTypes:

```
[Table("tblPackages")]
public class Packages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "No of SMS")]
    public int AllowedSMS { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Span in Days")]
    public int? TimeSpan { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int PackageTypesId {get;set;}

    public virtual PackageTypes {get;set;}
}


[Table("tblPackageTypes")]
public class PackageTypes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Packages> {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer states you need a navigation property. From your code I assume TypeId is FK to Id in PackageTypes. If this is so, simply create a property named Type of the type PackageType. When EF finds a navigation property to another entity it tries to find the property with the FK by appending the suffix Id or _Id.

If you on the other want a true composite object joining in fields from several tables you should use a view for this!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: By the way im new to ASP.NET and and also to EF so if there could be any helping post or tutorial it would be much better

Comment: Hi there! This is a really good book to get you started http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022220.do Also if you look at Microsofts official site for entity framework I think you'll find plenty of examples! Without looking through it, this article looks like a good starting point! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx